# iOS5 Modal Login No Longer Launches in XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, ios5

I can no longer show my Modal Login view controller when my app starts up since updating to XCode 4.2 and iOS5. I have a 4 tab tabBar app which requires an initial login to use. Since upgrading it just shows the first view that should be shown after logging in - basically it never loads the modal view controller responsible for handling the login and goes straight to the other functionality of the app. The exact same code that works in 4.3 doesn't work in iOS 5 - it has me stumped! I'd rather not use StoryBoard right now since this should work. I've pasted the viewDidLoad for the first tab on the tabBar below - it gets into the if statement but never actually shows the login view. I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me out! Am I missing something here? Thanks -

ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Call the super first
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Only login once
    PinPointMeAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PinPointMeAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // It's not loading like it did pre-iOS5 - why?
    NSLog(@"LOADING VIEW %d",appDelegate.loggedInFlag);

    // Only show the login view if we aren't logged in
    if (appDelegate.loggedInFlag == 0) {

        // Initialize our view controller that handles logging in
        ModalLogin *loginView = [[ModalLogin alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalLogin" bundle:nil];

        // Set the delegate to self
        loginView.delegate = self;

        // Animate presenting the nib "ModalPlace" modally
        loginView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:loginView animated:NO];

        // Set the flag that the modal login view is shown
        self.modalShown = 1;
    }

}
```

AppDelegateDidFinishLaunching:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Begin determining the User's Lat / Lon
    // Start the Location Manager to get current coordinates to determine where the mapview should zoom
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // Set the logged - in flag to 0 since we just launched
    loggedInFlag = 0;

    // Initially no alert views are shown
    alertViewShown = 0;

    // Initialize the splash screen to Not Shown
    splashScreenFlag = 0;

    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Set the delegate for the tabBarController
    tabBarController.delegate = self;

    // Un-Hide the status bar
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try presenting your modal on `viewDidAppear`, that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I did this and it does actually show the loading view now - but not until it actually briefly shows the other view behind that is not supposed to be seen until logged in. So it flashes the view not supposed to be seen for about .5 second and then correctly shows the login view. Any ideas how to correct this??

Comment: @Phil999 that is weird, that is what I am doing and it does not do that for me, do you have a Default.png?, that could be why I don't see it.

Comment: @Rob Bajorek I tried that for my application, but it would only work with viewDidAppear, but mine does not present the behavior the OP is talking about, and the first thing you see is the modal view with no flickering.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I did try viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad (viewDidLoad worked in 4.3) but neither worked with iOS5. viewDidAppear allowed the login to be shown but I am still getting a very short flicker of the view behind the modal login before the login view is shown. I'm not using any modal view animation and I also made sure my Default.png was there. Still trying to figure this one out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when working with iOS 5 compatibility.

As Oscar pointed out, you need to present your modal view in the `viewDidAppear`

Also, by default you probably have `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` in your AppDelegate `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

You have to make that call **after** your modal view is displayed.

The Default.png will be displayed until you make a UIWindow key and visible so you shouln't see a flickering anymore.